# One publication is hiding nested fields from another publication

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Given two publications for the same collection named Foo. The fooList should only return specific fields but the fooDetail should return the whole document.

Server:

```
Meteor.publish 'fooList', ->
    return Foo.find(
        {}
        { fields:
            foo: true
            'bar.bas': true
        })

Meteor.publish 'fooDetail', (foo_id) ->
    return Foo.find _id: foo_id
```

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe 'fooList'
Meteor.subscribe 'fooDetail', some_id
```

I expected to get the complete foo when subscribing to fooDetail. **But** all the fields from 'bar' (the nested document) are not available, except the 'bar.bas' field.

Is this a bug or should meteor work this way? (I'm currently on Meteor 1.0.3.2 and Iron-Router)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a bug, it's a [known limitation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/998) of the meteor's [MergeBox](https://meteorhacks.com/understanding-mergebox.html). It's one of those confusing problems that bites most meteor developers once.

From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe):

> If more than one subscription sends conflicting values for a field (same collection name, document ID, and field name), then the value on the client will be one of the published values, chosen arbitrarily.

You can see [this post](https://medium.com/@MaxDubrovin/workaround-for-meteor-limitations-if-you-want-to-sub-for-more-nested-fields-of-already-received-docs-eb3fdbfe4e07) for possible workarounds. In your example, you *could* modify your publish to look like:

```
Meteor.publish 'fooList', ->
  Foo.find {}, fields: foo: 1, bar: 1
```

That would publish all of the top-level `bar` field which avoids the conflict but may not be acceptable in your particular use case.

Comment: I don't understand how that sentence from the documentation addresses this situation.  In the above post, if one subscribed to foo and bar.bas, and then later wanted to subscribe to the bar.somethingelse field, that's not a conflict.  bar.bas and bar.somethingelse are not the same field name... ?? what am I missing?

Comment: I agree that the docs are not specific enough here. By field they mean a top-level field (`bar` in your example).

Answer (score 0):

Your pub/sub looks good. My guess is that you haven't added reactivity to the `fooDetail` sub. Do me a favor:

1. put both subs in a `waitOn` on iron router, passing in a static value to `fooDetail`.
2. Verify in minimongo that the other fields are there for the static id.
3. Wrap the sub in a `Template.Instance().autorun`