# Using Pub/Sub, how do I add additional fields if I previously subscribed to the collection with a limited set of fields?

Tags: meteor

If I have a subscription that does

```
Meteor.publish("mypublish", function (status) {
    var foundOnServer = MyCollection.find({"status": status}, {fields: {_id: 1, status: 1, "name": 1}});
    return foundOnServer;
  });
```

and I'm displaying those records in a table, then I want to let the user click on one of them to bring up the full detail of the record, and now I want to display some more fields that *weren't previously published* to the client, like maybe address, city, state, etc... how do I code things so that I can get the new fields picked up and put into the local minimongo collection, considering the record is already in the client.  Doing a Find just returns the document already in the client, without the extra fields I want.

EDIT: I was not aware of the DDP limitation in that once you subscribe to a field in a nested structure, you are unable to then add more fields from that level of the nested structure. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/998

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write another publish function for the appropriate subset and return more/all of the the fields. For example:

```js
Meteor.publish('singlePost', function(postId) {
  check(postId, String);
  return Posts.find(postId);
});
```

When you click on a post, you can subscribe to `singlePost` which will send all of the fields for that post. The key insight is the documents **will be merged on the client**.

So if the client had `{_id: 'x', message: 'hello'}` already in minimongo, and you later publish `{_id: 'x', color: 'blue'}`, the client will then have `{_id: 'x', message: 'hello', color: 'blue'}` in its database.

Comment: that's what I understood as well from reading tutorials on the subject, however, it isn't happening for me, and it must be something wrong with the way I'm doing things.  I put together a meteorpad... if you have time,  could you look at it please and see what I'm doing wrong.  I tried to make it as simple as possible.  If the instructions are in your way on every page, just comment them in the layout template  http://meteorpad.com/pad/xKnuw38ce64xCcqbR/DemoDrillDown

Comment: I can't look at it in detail right now, but I see you are publishing nested fields which makes for problems like the one you are describing. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969223/one-publication-is-hiding-nested-fields-from-another-publication) and let me know if that helps.

Comment: as a quick test, I removed the demographics nesting and it does work fine now.  But flattening out my entire document isn't viable, so I still need to try the solutions you referenced.  Thanks!

Comment: Wow, thanks again for finding this issue. It is not very clear in the docs! I'm not understanding the workarounds I've found so far but hopefully I can make something work, because I cannot afford to pull the whole set of fields up on the client when showing the summary lists.

Comment: gosh, it seems there should be a way to "drop" the document you're holding on to (the one with the limited set of fields) and then re-fetch (resubscribe/ re query) the full document you want with all the fields.

Comment: I think lots of implementations are _possible_, but this probably isn't a common enough issue for a large rework of the DDP internals. I'm guessing this isn't going to change anytime soon. Is changing your schema an option?

Comment: I'm evaluating whether I can migrate an old system that was using XML documents in oracle, and right now, I have just done a direct xml -> json mapping.  Given this new discovery, I will have to manually flatten out my json doc.  Not what I wanted to do but necessary for performance, because I can't be pulling up whole subdocuments until the user goes into the detail screen.

Comment: I found a workaround that was pretty easy to implement:  Number 5 in this explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/18880927/2799545 This effectively lets me create a "view" so I can have 2 separate publications, one that will have the limited set of fields, and another that will just be used when drilling into detail.