# Why my collection.find() does not work in meteor but work in robomongo?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a publication that should return me all users matching an `_id` array. here it the query:

```
Meteor.users.find({
            '_id': { $in: myArray}},{
                'profile.name':1,
                'profile.description':1,
                'profile.picture':1,
                'profile.website':1,
                'profile.country':1}
            );
```

When I run it in Robomongo (the mongo browser), it works. But my publication only returns `undefined`. when I `console.log(myArray);` in the publication, I get something like this `['FZ78Pr82JPz66Gc3p']`. This is what I paste in my working Robomongo query.

Alternative question: how can I have a better feedback(log) from the `Collection.find()` result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to specify fields in your [find](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find), which you can do like this:

```js
var options = {
  fields: {
    'profile.name': 1,
    'profile.description': 1,
    'profile.picture': 1,
    'profile.website': 1,
    'profile.country': 1
  }
};

Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: myArray}}, options);
```

However, if this is being used in a publish function, I **strongly** recommend using only top-level fields like so:

```js
Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: myArray}}, {fields: {profile: 1}});
```

For more details on why, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969223/one-publication-is-hiding-nested-fields-from-another-publication).

---

For your second question, you can view the documents returned by a cursor by calling [fetch](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) on it. For example:

```js
console.log(Posts.find({_id: {$in: postIds}}).fetch());
```

Comment: this is a nice anwser. Thank you for the `fetch()` trick, I should have guessed that. I'll read your link, try your approach and come back to validate/give a feedback. Thanks!

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you for correcting the missing `fields` key. I forgot it..... again :'(