# Meteor: publish 2 different projections of array elements

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have elements like this one in a collection:

```
{
    array: [{ a:10, b: {...} }, { a:30, b: {...} }, { a:50 b: {...} }]
}
```

In one publication, that can return hundreds of results, I project the array to
only have the `a` field and weigh less:

```
return Col.find({}, { fields: { 'array.a': 1 } })
```

In another one, I publish a single full document:

```
return Col.find({ _id: ObjectId(...) })
```

The 2nd publication is missing the fields excluded from each array item in
the first publication, **sometimes**. Refreshing the page (perhaps changing
the order of subscriptions?) fixes the bug.

How can I publish reduced array items in my large publication, and the full
elements in the single publication?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969223/one-publication-is-hiding-nested-fields-from-another-publication) - do you agree?

Comment: It _could be_. I'm not sure: the difference is that here, I'm using inner array element fields, which may have a different merging strategy. I would like to keep the question separate, while I investigate

Comment: Yeah I couldn't tell from your question if you are using sub-fields or not. Basically any time you project a subset of a given field (array, sub-document, etc.) you can get a conflict like this.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake above, projecting `a` instead of `array.a`. Fixed

Comment: Ah okay, that makes more sense. Unless you can think of a reason not to, I think I'll mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: You could potentially publish the small subset to a separate "virtual" collection on the client, which should prevent collisions at the cost of data duplication. I haven't tested the merging issue, but I did publish to such virtual client-only collections by directly observing cursors on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I examined different approaches. The problem can be solved on a case-by-case basis by carefully picking fields and minding subscription order, but these solutions are flimsy and rely on non-documented arbitrary conditions.

**The only real, generic solution is a virtual collection**. The simplest case is simply publishing a cursor under a different, client-side collection name. For example:

```
function publishVirtual(sub, name, cursor) {
  var observer = cursor.observeChanges({
    added  : function(id, fields) { sub.added(name, id, fields) },
    changed: function(id, fields) { sub.changed(name, id, fields) },
    removed: function(id)         { sub.remove(name, id) }
  })

  sub.onStop(function() {
    observer.stop() // important. Otherwise, it keeps running forever
  })
}
```

And then, in your publication, instead of returning a `cursor`:

```
var cursor = Users.find()
publishVirtual(this, 'virtualUsers', cursor)
this.ready()
```