# Publish a virtual collection in meteor

Tags: meteor, nosql

I'm trying to publish a collection with 2 different names.
freeCourses contains courses without paid_url field.
premiumCourses contains all courses which id exist in userCourses collection.

userCourses collection :

    `{    user_id: "1",     course_id: "1"    }`

```
Meteor.publish('freeCourses', function () {
            this.added('freeCourses', Courses.find({}, {fields: {'Seasons.Episodes.paid_url': 0}}));
            this.ready();
        });
        Meteor.publish('premiumCourses', function () {
            //userPremiumCourses is array of course_ids
            var userPremiumCourses = userCourses.find({'user_id': this.userId}, {fields: {course_id: 1, _id: 0}}).map(
                function (doc) {
                    return doc.course_id;
                }
            );
            this.added('premiumCourses', Courses.find({_id: {$in: userPremiumCourses}}));
            this.ready();
        });
if(Meteor.isClient){
Meteor.subscribe('freeCourses');
Meteor.subscribe('premiumCourses');
}
```

I want to get freeCourses and premiumCourses as two different collections on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I used publishVirtual function. thanks to @michel  floyd

```
function publishVirtual(sub, name, cursor) {
  var observer = cursor.observeChanges({
    added  : function(id, fields) { sub.added(name, id, fields) },
    changed: function(id, fields) { sub.changed(name, id, fields) },
    removed: function(id)         { sub.remove(name, id) }
  })

  sub.onStop(function() {
    observer.stop() // important. Otherwise, it keeps running forever
  })
}
```

and added this into publish :

```
Meteor.publish('freeCourses', function () {
    var cursor = Courses.find({}, {fields: {'Seasons.Episodes.paid_url': 0}});
    publishVirtual(this, 'freeCourses', cursor);
    this.ready();
});
Meteor.publish('premiumCourses', function () {
    //userPremiumCourses contains array of course_ids
    var userPremiumCourses = userCourses.find({'user_id': this.userId}, {fields: {course_id: 1, _id: 0}}).map(
        function (doc) {
            return doc.course_id;
        }
    );
    var cursor = Courses.find({_id: {$in: userPremiumCourses}});
    publishVirtual(this, 'premiumCourses', cursor);
    this.ready();
});
```

and made two client-side collections for subscribe :

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    freeCourses = new Mongo.Collection("freeCourses");
    premiumCourses= new Mongo.Collection("premiumCourses");

    Meteor.subscribe('freeCourses');
    Meteor.subscribe('premiumCourses');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen this done before but if it was possible I believe you would need to define two collections that referred to the same underlying mongo collection:

```
freeCourses = new Mongo.collection('userCourses');
premiumCourses = new Mongo.collection('userCourses');
```

I just tested that and that fails.

A collection can have multiple publications each with its own query parameters and fields but it appears you want something more like a SQL *view*. That doesn't exist in Meteor afaik.

Comment: Yea I tried what yo say. It doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Depends on how you hope to use these two different views. When you publish both views you are going to end up with the union of the documents being sent to the client. Each time you show a list of documents you're going to need to filter it by type.

Comment: Quite by accident I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33244410/2805154) to a related question that may help you - it talks about how to create a virtual collection!

Comment: thank you so much. I used the publishVirtual and this link that makes collection on client side. I'll add complete answer  here. [link](http://braindump.io/meteor/2014/09/20/publishing-to-an-alternative-clientside-collection-in-meteor.html)

Comment: Glad it worked out! I originally had no idea it was possible.