# Publish single field in an array, then republish multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a page that shows notifications. On this page as part of the layout is a small notifications icon that also shows the count of notifications.

To facilitate this I have two subscriptions running at the same time. Both on the `users` collection.

The first looks like this:

```
this.subscribe("user", {_id: Meteor.userId()}, {
  fields: {
    "notifications._id":1
  }
});
```

the second like this:

```
this.subscribe("user", {_id: Meteor.userId()}, {
  fields: {
    "notifications.title": 1,
    "notifications._id": 1,
    "notifications.level": 1
  }
});
```

The issue I'm having is that if the first subscription runs first (which it does), the second subscription doesn't publish the additional fields.

Is there a clean way of allowing multiple projections of the same collection (cleaner than this: [Meteor: publish 2 different projections of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221574/meteor-publish-2-different-projections-of-array-elements))

The publication `user` takes in a selector and set of fields and merges it with what the current user is allowed to see for the requested user - however this requirement makes no difference, even if I use different publications the issue remains.

It's likely that what I want can't be done, and I should just refactor and create a `notification` collection

Comment: What's the point of using 2 subs? Initial loading boost or something?

Comment: @RamilMuratov, they are in different templates. One is in a navigation bar and basically just shows the count, the other is a full page that shows all details